# Language settings description

Tags: software

I need a short description for some language settings in an app. You can set a text field behavior to support Latin characters (read left to right), Arabic and other languages that read right to left and languages like Greek that read left to right.

How to describe that?

Comment: 'Text direction'?

Comment: Welcome to ELU! http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct like:

> To set the flow of text RTL for Arabic, Persian Urdu e.t.c **do this**,  or else, set it LTR for Latin languages.

Of course, alter "**do this**" with "what to be done"

Comment: RTL is an accepted term for Right-to-Left in the context of language settings. The alternative being 'Default' that is, Left-to-Right.